# How to copy (duplicate) a page?

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to just simply copy a page. Inside the pages list i am trying to make a copy of my home.aspx page. example: I want to make a copy of "home" and name it "home 2".

I have tried downloading the file, renaming, and then update document to pages. This does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe use the Copy action from **Site Settings ->**  (Site Administration) **Content & Structure**

[image]

*But be careful, it might actually do what it says and make a copy*

Comment: haha yes it did actually make a copy. that's a win for sharepoint.